# Deserialize class that implements Map as a bean

Tags: java, json, dictionary, javabeans, jackson-databind

The [`Playlist`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/blob/main/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3/1.31.0/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Playlist.java) class implements [`Map<String, Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).  Jackson deserializes a child object into a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/MapDeserializer.html) and then calls `Map.put()`.  This throws an exception because the `Map.put()` implementation is trying to assign the `LinkedHashMap` to a field of another type.  Jackson calls `Map.put()` because it is using a [`MapDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/MapDeserializer.html).  How do I change the deserializer to avoid calling `Map.put()`?

I figure if I tell Jackson to use a [`BeanDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializer.html) instead of a `MapDeserializer`, then everything will deserialize without a problem.  Is there a better way?

**Attempt #1**

I created a [`JsonDeserializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) and overrode `deserialize()` with this code:

```
return BeanDeserializerFactory.instance.
   createBeanDeserializer(context, m_type, m_description).
   deserialize(parser, context);
```

Unfortunately, this throws `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No _valueDeserializer assigned`.  I am not sure how to assign `_valueDeserializer`.

**Attempt #2**

I then created a [`BeanDeserializerModifier`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializerModifier.html) and overrode `modifyMapDeserializer()` with this code:

```
DeserializationContext context;

if (!type.equals(m_type))
{
   return deserializer;
}
         
context = ??????;

try
{
   return BeanDeserializerFactory.instance.createBeanDeserializer(context, type, beanDesc);
}
catch (JsonMappingException caught)
{
   throw new UncheckedIOException(caught);
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the [`DeserializationContext`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext.html).